# What is the relationship between ports and Nodejs? What does a port mean to NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

In Node, a server will *'listen'* on a port.

What information comes in to the port? In what format is the information, JS? How does Node transform the information?

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_server_listen.asp

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_traffic

Answer (score 0):

Ports are like harbors (thus the word port) for servers. On a server there may run several applications that communicate over the internet so you need to know which application you want to talk to (or on which harbor your ship wants to dock). The web server or the mail server? This is identified by the port. Web servers usually use port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS).

What happens in your node application is that a socket gets opened and it listens on all incoming traffic on port 8080. So it won't work if you type in `localhost` into your browser (as this by default uses port 80), so you have to type in `localhost:8080`.

If you want more information on ports, just google `ports networking` because it has nothing to do with nodejs.